# How to directly access text in AxAcroPDFLib?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, axacropdf

I have a COM component of class `AxAcroPDF` which is part of `Adobe acrobat 7.0 browser control type library 1.0`.

I would like to search text inside the PDF like it would be a `String` is it possible?

I went through: http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/pdf/iac/IACReference.pdf

```
 public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
            //axAcroPDF1.LoadFile("C:/cw3_31paz.pdf");
            axAcroPDF1.src = "C:/cw3_31paz.pdf";
            axAcroPDF1.setShowToolbar(false);
            axAcroPDF1.setView("FitH");
            axAcroPDF1.setLayoutMode("SinglePage");           
        }
```

but I don't know how to get access to the text inside directly so I could process it.

Comment: wouldn't that be on page `236` of the document that you posted look at the `GetText` Method

Comment: @DJKRAZE For some reason I don't have some of methods posted in the documention. For instance I don't have `Find` method and `GetText` also. I left Adobe Activex and now I try my luck with Expert PDF EditorX , but it's hard to find example of usage.